# C# - version of .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the following error message:

> Unable to resolve the primary reference "Xilium.CefGlue" because it was created with the Framework ".NETFramework, Version = v4.5". This version is higher than the current target Framework ".NETFramework, Version = v4.0, Profile = Client"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is set to build for dotNet 4.0. Go into the project settings(`Properties> Application> Target Framework`) and change it to 4.5.